# Does Play support separate routes files per environment - dev, uat, prod?

Tags: playframework

Is it possible to have the following routing in dev mode:

```
GET  /       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/ui/dev", file="index.html")
GET  /*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/ui/dev", file)
```

and the following in production:

```
GET  /       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/ui/prod", file="index.html")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Declare your dev routes in `conf/routes`, but declare your production routes in `conf/prod.routes`.  Then, have a production configuration file, `conf/prod.conf`, and put this in it:

```
include "application.conf"

application.router = "prod.Routes"
```

Now, when you start your application in production, simply use:

```
path/to/myapp/bin/myapp -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf -Dhttp.port=...
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this method if both route files define a path to the same method (e.g. `GET / controllers.News.foo()`)? I'm getting a `ReverseNews is already defined as class ReverseNews` compilation error...

Answer (score 1):

The solution above works well but means you are duplicating routes for e.g. non-static resources in your `routes` and `prod.routes` files.

If you want to keep a single routes file, you can go down the road that [johanandren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219125/johanandren) proposes. I use this method quite successfully, and have posted a gist for this method at https://gist.github.com/drcharris/2e3518b212adfa1b6a7f

Comment: Updated version of ConfigurableAssets for PlayFramework 2.5

https://gist.github.com/cessationoftime/b304c13f810f9d52e32fbf6c778af3d9

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. But here you have two ideas of how you might achieve the same functionality:

- write a thin wrapper around Assets.at that looks at the current env and handles it differently, and then just calling Assets.at with the modified path
- override how routing is done in Global, this is a bit hard to do if you want to keep using the routes DSL for both prod and dev routes file as you would have to figure out to get them compiled