# Are imports and conditionals in Play's routes file possible?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I know that the earlier versions of Play used to support routes and conditionals (if blocks) in the routes file but I cannot find any such documentation for Play 2.2.x and [HTTP routing](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting) says nothing about such a feature.

I want to replace this:

```
GET /api/users/:id com.corporate.project.controllers.UserController.get(id)
```

with a shorter version using `import` as follows:

```
import com.corporate.project.controllers._ 

GET /api/users/:id UserController.get(id)
```

Also, is it possible to have conditionals in the routes file? e.g.

```
if Play.isDev(Play.current())
  GET /displayConfig   DebugController.displayServerConfigs()
```

Comment: If you need conditional routing to that specific case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21054584/1205368

Answer (score 5):

Package imports used to be possible with an SBT setting: `routesImport += "com.corporate.project.controllers._"`. Not sure if it is still the case.

> Also, is it possible to have conditionals in the routes file?

It might not be an ideal solution but we use routes tags to deal with this kind of conditional routes. You need a filter that checks if the route is annotated and runs your conditional logic.

Routes:

```
# @devmode
GET /displayConfig   DebugController.displayServerConfigs()
```

Filter:

```
object DevmodeRouteFilter extends Filter {

  private val DevmodeAnnotation = "@devmode"

  override def apply(next: RequestHeader => Future[SimpleResult])(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    if(isDevRoute(request) && !Play.isDev(Play.current()) {
      Play.current.global.onHandlerNotFound(request)
    } else {
      next(request)
    }
  }

  private def isDevRoute(request: RequestHeader): Boolean = {
    val comments = request.tags.getOrElse(Routes.ROUTE_COMMENTS, "")
    comments.lines.exists { comment =>
      comment.trim == DevmodeAnnotation
    }
  }

}
```

Don't forget to add the filter to the filter chain.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your question, it is an interesting idea, so I went to the sources of Play2 and found that in my checkout of Play 2.2.3 in the play.core.Router.scala: object HandlerInvoker constructs controller as

```
handlerDef.ref.getClass.getClassLoader.loadClass(handlerDef.controller)
```

So I am afraid that support for partial class names (stored in handlerDef.controller) is not implemented in 2.2.x.

In 2.3.x there is commit https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/ba98dabd7ba374ed98f14f721835b898d27dd55b
that brought notion of package/namespace for the routes.

Please see changes in Routes.scala and RoutesCompiler.scala from that commit.

But I can't find description of that functionality in the documentation and I do not have Play 2.3.x to play with it now.

P.S.: Sample magic for advanced routing for 2.3.x described in http://java.dzone.com/articles/advanced-routing-play .